# Randomly distributing amount X to n items

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The following exemplary data are available:

**df_1**

```
DATE      AMOUNT
20170101  50000
20170102  55000
20170103  60000
20170104  65000
...       ...
20171231  150000
```

**df_2**

```
DATE      INVNR   AMOUNT
20170101  ...     ???
20170101  ...     ???
20170101  ...     ???
20170101  ...     ???
20170102  ...     ???
20170102  ...     ???
20170103  ...     ???
...       ...     ???
20171231  ...     ???
20171231  ...     ???
20171231  ...     ???
20171231  ...     ???
```

This is the expected exemplary output:

**df_ramdomly_distributed_amounts**

```
DATE      INVNR   AMOUNT
20170101  ...     14879
20170101  ...     6523
20170101  ...     8596
20170101  ...     20002
20170102  ...     31548
20170102  ...     23452
20170103  ...     60000
...       ...     ???
20171231  ...     26428
20171231  ...     72658
20171231  ...     326
20171231  ...     50593
```

The column **INVNR** holds invoice numbers but those are system exports and **not consistent**. **DATE** is always in the given format and can be manipulated if needed (df_1 + df_2 hold it as a string column at the moment).

So the task is to randomly distribute the AMOUNT of each unique DATE stored in df_1 in a 1:m relationship to the invoices in df_2. The amount of invoices for every day varies over time. df_2 holds ~ 200,000 invoices at the moment. I cannot wrap my head around a solution right now. Thanks a lot for any tip!

Comment: Can you post your current code? What have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:-

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

# intialise data of lists & Create DataFrame
data1 = {'DATE': ['20170101', '20170102', '20170103', '20170104'],
         'AMOUNT': ['500', '600', '400', '800']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {'DATE': ['20170101', '20170101', '20170101', '20170102', '20170102', '20170103', '20170103', '20170104'],
         'INVNR': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'd1']}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print("------------- DF 1 --------------------")
print(df_1)
print("------------- DF 2 --------------------")
print(df_2)

# process each date group and split the amount among them
def splitAndAddAmount(gr, df_am):
    amount = int(df_am.loc[df_am['DATE'] == gr['DATE'].iloc[0], 'AMOUNT'].iloc[0])
    grpLength = int(len(gr))
    assert amount >= grpLength >= 1
    pieces = []
    for idx in range(grpLength - 1):
        pieces.append(randint(1, amount - sum(pieces) - grpLength + idx))
    pieces.append(amount - sum(pieces))
    gr['AMNT'] = pieces
    return gr


print("------------- DF FINAL --------------------")
df_final = df_2.groupby('DATE').apply(splitAndAddAmount, df_1)
print(df_final)
```

output:-

```
------------- DF 1 --------------------
       DATE AMOUNT
0  20170101    500
1  20170102    600
2  20170103    400
3  20170104    800
------------- DF 2 --------------------
       DATE INVNR
0  20170101    a1
1  20170101    a2
2  20170101    a3
3  20170102    b1
4  20170102    b2
5  20170103    c1
6  20170103    c2
7  20170104    d1
------------- DF FINAL --------------------
       DATE INVNR  AMNT
0  20170101    a1    29
1  20170101    a2   148
2  20170101    a3   323
3  20170102    b1    23
4  20170102    b2   577
5  20170103    c1   261
6  20170103    c2   139
7  20170104    d1   800
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot and is exactly what I was searching for. Trying to walk through your code step by step, rebuild it and understand how it works. If you find the time, I would appreciate a lot if you write up a little paragraph how everything works. 
I understand the inner part as well as how everything merges. But where do we specify that we want to iterate over all groups of dates? Does the .apply on the grouped DF return smth. that helps there?

Comment: you are welcome. Here we are grouping df_2 by date and by processing each with splitAndAddAmount(). This will randomly split the amount with group length.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) for both columns, and for the second, multiply by random samples from a a dirichlet distribution using [`numpy.random.dirichlet`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html), since we know that they will add up to `1`:

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
random_dist = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(n), size=df.shape[0])

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE' : df.DATE.repeat(n),
                   'AMOUNT' : df.AMOUNT.repeat(n).mul(random_dist.ravel())
                      })

print(df)

     DATE        AMOUNT
0  20170101  36751.437762
0  20170101   3592.760077
0  20170101   9655.802161
1  20170102  28771.004963
1  20170102  17277.411089
1  20170102   8951.583948
2  20170103   6502.473089
2  20170103  49928.084247
2  20170103   3569.442664
3  20170104   5185.404276
3  20170104  54048.869887
3  20170104   5765.725837
4  20171231  70684.665661
4  20171231  57444.889083
4  20171231  21870.445257
```

---

We could check the above is ok with:

```
df.groupby('DATE').AMOUNT.sum()

DATE
20170101     50000.0
20170102     55000.0
20170103     60000.0
20170104     65000.0
20171231    150000.0
Name: AMOUNT, dtype: float64
```

And where:

```
print(random_dist)

array([[0.73502876, 0.0718552 , 0.19311604],
       [0.52310918, 0.31413475, 0.16275607],
       [0.10837455, 0.83213474, 0.05949071],
       [0.07977545, 0.83152108, 0.08870347],
       [0.4712311 , 0.38296593, 0.14580297]])

print(random_dist.sum(1))

array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Comment: Thank you! Only problem here is, that n=3 produces 3 invoices for every date, but the amount of invoices is set / has to be derived from df_2, i.e. for my exemplary data we have:
    20170101  4 times; 
    20170102  2 times; 
    20170103  1 times; 
    20171231  4 times

Comment: Then you can't vectorize this. You could adapt my solution by encapsulating it in a function and apply to each group @fynn